# Trigger angularjs modal when logged in user session times out

Tags: angularjs, session

I am new to AngularJS. Another developer put together our eCommerce platform using AngularJS as part of the solution. We have AngularJS built modal overlays and I am converting all our AngularJS alert() to use the modal.

So far, so good, except the final alert() - one that is triggered when the logged in user session times out. We are using http://adamalbrecht.com/2013/12/12/creating-a-simple-modal-dialog-directive-in-angular-js/ to build our modal directive but I can't get this to work without user input - these modals are all triggered by users clicking buttons and inputs but this is not triggered by a user action. Everything I've tried has resulted in ReferenceError: $scope is not defined

I would like to share the code but it is owned by the company so I can't share it. Just wondering if anyone out there has put together an AngularJS modal that triggers when the user log in session timesout to tell them they need to log back in.

Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to guess w/o seeing any code.

Comment: I understand. Mostly I'm looking for anyone who has solved this problem so I can understand where to start.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem in Single Page Applications. With Angular you can solve it with $http interceptor.

The idea is if the session is expired the first time when the user needs some action from the backend to be redirected to the login page or modal dialog used for login to be shown. Expired session is detected from the response itself.

Example:

```
.factory('httpAuthInterceptor', function ($q) {
  return {
    'responseError': function (response) {
      // NOTE: detect error because of unauthenticated user
      if ([401, 403].indexOf(response.status) >= 0) {
        // NOTE: here you can trigger login modal dialog opening 
        return response;
      } else {
        return $q.reject(rejection);
      }
    }
  };
})

.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpAuthInterceptor');
});
```

Comment: How do I trigger the modal dialog? from within the if(){} statement? Everything I try comes back with a "ReferenceError: $scope is not defined" in the browser.

Comment: You can broadcast an event on the $rootScope for example.

Comment: Found this is my Google search for "how do i open an angularjs modal inside a .factory?" http://codepen.io/capelo/pen/wKeEA. Trying to figure out how to get it to wrok.

Comment: We already have a .factory handling the logout. I need to figure out how to get it to trigger an overlay modal instead of the alert.

Comment: Just read I can't use a $scope inside a .factory. I'm looking into broadcasting an event on the $rootScope.